# Inheritance and Strongly Typed Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, razor

I have an abstract class *foo* that contains some properties and methods. I have also have a number of classes that implement *foo* such as *barfoo* and *foobar*.

To safe rewriting the same code over multiple different views I've created a strongly typed partial view

```
@model List<foo>
@foreach (var x in Model) {
<div> x.SomeProperty </div>
}
```

Sadly, when I attempt to call this view with

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("PartialView", List<Foobar>); }
```

I get the following error

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Namespace.Models.Foobar]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Namespace.Models.Foo]'.

Is what I'm trying to do possible at all or will I just have to duplicate code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying exactly what you're trying isn't possible. If all you're doing is enumerating over the collection (rather than modifying it), you could change to the following and things should be ok:

```
@model IEnumerable<foo>
@foreach (var x in Model) {
    <div> x.SomeProperty </div>
}
```

The problem is fairly easy to understand if you really think about it.

Your Model is a `List<foo>`. That means that it should be entirely possible to say `Model.Add(new Barfoo());`.

You're trying to pass a `List<Foobar>` as the Model. Obviously, `Model.Add(new Barfoo());` would fail in that case because it's not possible.

Using a covariant interface like IEnumerable allows you to do exactly what you need.

Comment: You can't add items to IEnumerable<T> (since IENumerable<T> has no `Add()` method) but to ICollection<T> instead. Thus, the model passed in has to implement ICollection<T> to allow adding items to it.

Comment: @Marius - Correct, but there's no good reason to allow the adding of items in the Model (unless you're using Model Binding to post an updated collection to the server, in which case you should be using a ViewModel class).

Answer (score 2):

You could do it as:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("ParialView", list.Cast<Foo>().ToList()); }
```

The runtime type of `List<FooBar>` is not the same as `List<Foo>`, and as you're not using covariant interfaces, you can't assume it will accept the implicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

`List<Foo> does not inherit from List<Foobar>` so that's why this won't work...

Answer (score 0):

How about feeding the partial view a collection of Foo instead of a collection of FooBar?

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("PartialView", MyFoobBarList.Cast<Foo>().ToList()); }
```

(by the way, do you really need the list?)